# MongoDB not able to uninstall(Ubuntu 14.04 and MongoDB 2.6.4.)

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and MongoDB 2.6.4. I have installed packages - mongodb-org=2.6.4 mongodb-org-server=2.6.4 mongodb-org-shell=2.6.4 mongodb-org-mongos=2.6.4 mongodb-org-tools=2.6.4

I can see MongoDB directory on /opt/bitnami/mongodb path

I tried following command but not getting any packages

`sudo dpkg -l | grep mongo`

Can you please help me how to uninstall MongoDB ?

Comment: Did you tried my post?

Answer (score 0):

Use command :

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove package-name
```

In your case :

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove mongodb mongodb-clients mongodb-server mongodb-dev
```

It will purge required packages along with dependencies that are installed with mongodb.

`--auto-remove` option work similar to `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Run below command to search for installed mongo packages with dpkg :

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep mongo
```

If the above command still returns a list of packages with mongo in the name.

Then try using a wildcard search for the name:

```
sudo apt-get remove mongodb* --purge
```